# How to save csv files with quotes escaped by slash?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

While there are tons of questions on python csv quoting, I believe I have hit a case that was not covered.

I have some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = [(1, '1\' 2"',), (2, '1\' 4"')]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['months', 'height'])
print(df.head())

df.to_csv('blah.csv', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, 
          quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
```

It produces the following output:

```
   months height
0       1  1' 2"
1       2  1' 4"
```

Saved to a csv, it looks like:

```
months,height
1,"1' 2"""
2,"1' 4"""
```

However, I would like it to look like this:

```
months,height
1,"1' 2\""
2,"1' 4\""
```

(In case you're wondering, that's the output format from Spark's default csv writer.)

Where the double quotes are escaped. I couldn't find a way to do this... any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `doublequote=False` (it defaults to True), also `quoting=QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`:

```
df.to_csv('blah.csv', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, 
      quotechar='"', escapechar='\\', doublequote=False)
```

See docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Output:

```
"months","height"
1,"1' 2\""
2,"1' 4\""
```

Comment: Great, was missing the `doublequote`. Thanks!